# Query result turned crazy with count() and sum()

Tags: sql, ms-access

(First question on StackOverflow, New on SQL with MSAccess. Please advise if I am missing anything or wrong format.)

I have two tables [Summary] and [Detail] with the layout as follow:

[Summary]

| Driver ID | DateOfOperation | SalaryMonth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/23/2023 | 2/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1/21/2023 | 2/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1/23/2023 | 2/1/2023 |

...Record Total:18734

[Detail]

| Driver ID | DateOfOperation | WorkOrder | Points | SalaryMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 1 | 400 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 2 | 118 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 3 | 118 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 4 | 118 | 2/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1/21/2023 | 1 | 462 | 2/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1/21/2023 | 2 | 1264 | 2/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1/23/2023 | 1 | 924 | 2/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1/23/2023 | 2 | 1264 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 1 | 260 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 2 | 354 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 3 | 236 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 4 | 260 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 5 | 236 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 6 | 236 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 7 | 236 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 8 | 236 | 2/1/2023 |
| 24 | 1/21/2023 | 9 | 236 | 2/1/2023 |

...Record Total: 52838

I attempted to

1. count the total days in a period (eg.month) a driver work; &
2. Calculate total points of a driver got in a period.
3. Average points of a driver got in a period.

I ran the query with the SQL as follow.  The query ran unusually long and the numbers on CountDateOfOperation and Month_points turned haywired like 1003922 days in a month.

```
SELECT Summary.[Driver ID], Count(Summary.DateOfOperation) AS CountDateOfOperation, Sum([Points]) AS Month_Points
FROM Summary, Detail
WHERE (((Summary.DateOfOperation) Between [Begin Date?] And [end date?]))
GROUP BY Summary.[Driver ID];
```

Expected result:

[Begin Date?] - 12/21/2022
[end date?]   - 1/20/2023

| Driver ID | CountDateOfOperation | Month_Points | SalaryMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 19 | 18794 | 1/1/2023 |
| 30 | 25 | 26548 | 1/1/2023 |

...Record Total: 39

Actually result:

[Begin Date?] - 12/21/2022
[end date?]   - 1/20/2023

| Driver ID | CountDateOfOperation | Month_Points | SalaryMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 1003922 | 293134356 | 1/1/2023 |
| 30 | 1320950 | 385703100 | 1/1/2023 |

...Record Total: 39

May anyone tell me what's wrong with the SQL and how to resolve this issue?

#################################

Thank you for your prompt reply (which scared me a bit...)

I used Access to link up the tables and the SQL turned out likes below:

```
SELECT Summary.[Driver ID], Count(Summary.DateOfOperation) AS CountDateOfOperation, Sum([Points]) AS Month_Points, Summary.SalaryMonth

FROM Drivers INNER JOIN (Summary INNER JOIN Detail ON (Summary.SalaryMonth = Detail.Salary_month) AND (Summary.DateOfOperation = Detail.[Date of Operation]) AND (Summary.[Driver ID] = Detail.[Driver ID])) ON (Drivers.[Driver ID] = Summary.[Driver ID]) AND (Drivers.[Driver ID] = Detail.[Driver ID])

WHERE (((Summary.DateOfOperation) Between [Begin Date?] And [end date?]))

GROUP BY Summary.[Driver ID], Summary.SalaryMonth;
```

The outcome is making a lot more sense, but still not accurate...

Actually result:

[Begin Date?] - 12/21/2022
[end date?]   - 1/20/2023

| Driver ID | CountDateOfOperation | Month_Points | SalaryMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 80 | 18794 | 1/1/2023 |
| 30 | 50 | 26548 | 1/1/2023 |

...Record Total: 39

Just found that CountDateOfOperation is now counting Detail.WorkOrder instead of Summary.DateOfOperation.

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Thank you all.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: `FROM Summary INNER JOIN Detail ON Summary.[Driver ID] = Detail.[Driver ID]`.  Without linking the two tables, you are effectively doing a cartesian join, which is why 1) it takes so long and 2) the results are sky high.

Comment: You have 2 tables but your WHERE is using 1 table. This is usually not what you want. You need to have a condition to join/relate the two tables. Read about joining tables and/or use MS-SQL Query Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the Summary table. There's nothing in it that is not in Detail.

Test Data [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1whg--s3)

```
CREATE TABLE #detail ( Driver_ID INT
                     , DateOfOperation DATE
                     , WorkOrder INT
                     , Points INT
                     , SalaryMonth DATE);
INSERT INTO #detail 
       VALUES
       ( 24,    '1/21/2023',    1,  400,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    2,  118,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    3,  118,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    4,  118,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 30,    '1/21/2023',    1,  462,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 30,    '1/21/2023',    2,  1264,   '2/1/2023')
      ,( 30,    '1/23/2023',    1,  924,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 30,    '1/23/2023',    2,  1264,   '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    1,  260,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    2,  354,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    3,  236,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    4,  260,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    5,  236,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    6,  236,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    7,  236,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    8,  236,    '2/1/2023')
      ,( 24,    '1/21/2023',    9,  236,    '2/1/2023');
```

Query - I wrote this in SQL Server but I believe it should work in Access.

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DATE = '2023-01-01'
      , @EndDate DATE = '2023-02-01'
 SELECT Driver_ID
      , COUNT(Distinct DateOfOperation) DaysWorked
      , SUM(points) TotalPointsEarned
      , SUM(Points)/COUNT(DISTINCT DateOfOperation) PointsPerWorkDay
      , SalaryMonth
   FROM #detail
  WHERE DateOfOperation BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate  
  GROUP BY Driver_ID, SalaryMonth
```

Returns:

| Driver_ID | DaysWorked | TotalPointsEarned | AvgPointsPerWorkDay | SalaryMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 1 | 3044 | 3044 | 2023-02-01 |
| 30 | 2 | 3914 | 1957 | 2023-02-01 |

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Although the expected result for DaysWorked should be 1 day for driver-24 and 2 days for driver-30.  This is the issue I am facing from the very beginning and this is why I used Summary table for counting work days instead.

Comment: Sorry. Brain quit working briefly. It's a simple fix. Count( Distinct DateOfOperation) gets the right count. I also updated the PointsPerWorkDay and added SalaryMonth.

Comment: Distinct!  That's something I'm looking for! Unfortunately Access does not allow Distinct in Count(), but this is a way to go!